# Inverse of an infinite sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

What exactly prevents me (or, if I'm just paranoid, doesn't) from making operations such as inverses on summations?

For instance, can I say that

$$({\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n})^{-1}=(-\frac{1}{12})^{-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}=-12?$$

I can already tell this may be wrong, but either way, I would like to know exactly why and where I may look up rules and axioms of summation in case my mind ever comes across something like this again. I thank you in advance.

Comment: An infinite sum of a sequence $a_n$ is defined as $\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n= 1}^N a_n$. So it is the limit of the sequence of partial sums, i.e keep adding and and see what happens for $N$ large (stated fairly irrigorously but I think it gets the point across). You can define inverses on summation, but that formula above is incorrect, if we define $\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n= 1}^N a_n = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}a_n$. So it all really depends on how infinite sums are defined. There are other ways of defining series, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation

Comment: $\sum_\limits{1}^\infty n$ only equals $1$ if you are using non-standard summation techniques such as Ramanujan summation.  As for the rest of the algebra $(\sum a_n)^{-1}\ne \sum (a_n^{-1})$ and the very simple example $\frac {1}{a+b} \ne a+b$ should make that clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for one, exponentiation (of which inversion is a type) doesn't distribute over addition, so this won't work even for finite sums; e.g., $(2+2)^{-1} \neq 2^{-1}+2^{-1}$. You want to make sure something works for finite sums before you try it on infinite sums.